# Akka in a nutshell

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm triying to figure out how to work with Akka in Scala. Did I get it right that, what I need to do is instead of this:

```
class Class1 {
  def someMethod1 = {
    //.... some operations....
    "someStringData"
  }

  def someMethod2(param1: Int, param2: Double, param3: BigInt) = {
    //.... some operations....
    new someClass
  }
}

//.............................
object Application extends App {
  val c = new Class1
  val stringData = c.someMethod1
  val someClass = c.someMethod2
}
```

I must do this:

```
case object SomeMethod
case class SomeClass(a: Int, b: Double, c: BigInt)
case class SomeReturnClass(d: Boolean)

class Class1 extends Actor{
  def receive = {
    case SomeMethod => {
      //.... some operation....
      sender ! "someStringData"
    }

    case SomeClass(a, b, c) => {
     //...some operations....
     val result: Boolean = ..... // some operations.... 
     sender ! new SomeReturnClass(result)
    }
  }
}

//.............................

object Application extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("HelloSystem")
  val helloActor = system.actorOf(Props[Class1], name = "helloactor")
  val stringData: String = helloActor ! someMethod1
  val someClass: SomeReturnClass = helloActor ! someMethod2
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have got the basic idea right, the only error is in how you try to get the actor's answer: for that please have a look at the [ask pattern](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/scala/actors.html#Ask__Send-And-Receive-Future). Actors are like "active objects" in a sense, but not every object should be translated into an actor; it is not uncommon to use plain object composition when implementing actors.

Comment: but I don't Future here.

Comment: what do you mean? your code does not compile because "!" does not return what you assume it does.

Comment: You're right. However, I've seen these docs and that's why I asked the question.

Comment: Which docs? Please note that Akka 1.x.x and 2.x.x are _very_ different and there are quite a lot of differences even between the 2.x versions. Please always make sure that you are looking at the docs of the right version.